# Full screen dual monitor RDP session moves all apps to first monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I sometimes RDP into work (Win10) from home (Win7). I have dual monitors for both setups. I have full-screen and use-all-my-monitors set in the RDP config file. However, when my session connects and displays it does its remote resolution adjusting and moves everything that was displayed on the second monitor to the first. This is very annoying. I have apps that I want to stay on the second monitor. How do I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 Ultimate/Entreprise? Dual-screen is [only supported](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7s-remote-desktop-connection/) on those versions. Windows 10 supports it if the remote computer is either W10 Pro/Enterprise.

Comment: Of course. If I didn't, then my question would be "why can't I dual monitor?"

Comment: brock, you don't need to be so stand off-ish like that! @CaldeiraG was only asking for some more information that you didn't have in your original question.

Comment: Although I've experienced this for years, I've always just put it down to the way remote desktop works. You could try team viewer or vnc perhaps?

Comment: @Smock Yeah, TV, VNC, Anydesk, etc. do the right thing. Hmm... Maybe it's always been like this? For the past 5 years or so the aforementioned solutions were the only solutions I could use, that is, I couldn't RDP before, but now I can and this is annoying. Oh well, hopefully someone knows that "gotcha" we have to handle.